# Android TabHost - catch back button

Tags: android, dialog, android-tabhost, back, confirm

I have an Android app that uses TabHost, the activity that calls the others based on the selected tab is simply called Main.java.  I have tried to override the on back button event inside of the Main.java class, however it does not seem to see it.  I am trying to display a dialog window and confirm with the user that they want to sign out, and if they click OK have it completely close the app (not just send to background) and if they click Cancel, obviously have it stay open.  Any suggestions as to why this doesn't seem to work?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{               
     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
     alert.setMessage("Test dialog");
     alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Is Main.java the Activity?

Comment: Please don't override the backbutton like that. It's not standard behaviour on Android and hence should never be implemented. Your users will have your head for breakfast if you decide to implement it. Instead, if you need to log the user out, log him out when the app closes.

Comment: Main is the activity that has the tabHost, but when the user clicks the different tabs, it starts a new intent inside of the tabcontent for that activity.  So if they click Status for example, it starts the Status activity, but within the tabcontent in Main.java.  I appreicate your input Darwind, but I NEED a confirmation dialog to verify the user wants to sign out.

Comment: be cautious messing with standard Android app behavior ... i.e. overriding Back button, or Task management, users will get confused.  Put a big LOGOUT button on your main task, have it automatically signout after time period, etc, but don't change Back button.

Comment: Understood, I'll look into logging the user out when the app closes as suggested by Darwind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It turns out to be pretty easy. Add the following code to your child tab activity :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
}
```

> Then in the TabActivity do the real logic:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// Called by children
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
 alert.setMessage("Test dialog");
 alert.show();
}
```

> Otherwise, the children will intercept and consume the event without notifying the tab host.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is coming very late but it may still help someone

Please add the below code to the TabActivity that is hosting other activities and also add the code to every child Activity that is been hosted with the Tabhost. it worked for me.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 5
                && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            Log.d("CDA", "onKeyDown Called");
            onBackPressed();
            return true; 
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
       Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(setIntent);
    }
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi All below is my solution for this question -

//////---------------------------/////////////

FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getParent() instanceof TabHostActivity) {
        int count = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count == 0){
            // TODO: Call your exist alert
        }
        else{
             super.onBackPressed();  
        }
    }
    else{
         super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}


//////---------------------------/////////////
```